# No Facebook login screen in django social auth

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I am trying to build a small page using django which uses a facebook login, and I am using the django-social-auth package from agiliq: https://github.com/agiliq/Django-Socialauth and trying to follow the documentation.

However, I am not able to see/test the login from facebook.

The settings.py and urls.py can be found here: http://dpaste.com/685141/

When I go to: 127.0.0.1:8000/login/facebook I get the following error from facebook:

```
f Error:
An error occurred. Please try later
```

where, f is the facebook sprite.

As I understand, I think I need to specify the redirect url (?) but I am not entirely sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well First of all I don't see the SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS setting

mine is like this:
SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS  = ('twitter','facebook','google')

Also be advised that facebook will never return an ok state for a remote url that does not match the domain name you said you had in your app.

So localhost != domain name is not cool to them.

also I'd advise if you took down your dpaste because your keys, email and root password are exposed.

Comment: Juan, According to their documentation, "All backends are enabled by default." <http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html> Is that not true?

Comment: Even if they are enabled by default, he has a point that this will not work from localhost. You need to be testing it from the domain you set it up with on facebook.

Comment: Juan, obviously, my dpaste does not contain the correct username/passwords :)

Comment: Juan, Jdi: OK. I understand that localhost!=domain name; but, how does one go about testing then? Is it possible to somehow map it to localhost? Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Well if you have DNS zone access to your domain, you can try to point it to your public IP something like login.mydomain.com,  its a matter of playing with your router, and DNS.

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse [django-socialauth](https://github.com/agiliq/Django-Socialauth) with [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth), they try to solve the same but on quite different ways.